# model missing required attr_accessor for 'avatar_file_name'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

On my app in production mode digitalocean I configured Paperclip but i have this problem:

```
I, [2016-04-08T15:17:29.169827 #23709]  INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 16ms (ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)
F, [2016-04-08T15:17:29.171143 #23709] FATAL -- :
Paperclip::Error (CommercialActivity model missing required attr_accessor for 'avatar_file_name'):
  app/controllers/commercial_activities_controller.rb:50:in `create'
```

commercial_activity.rb

```
class CommercialActivity < ActiveRecord::Base
   ...
  has_attached_file :avatar, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment :avatar, content_type: { content_type: ["image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png"] }
   ...
end
```

Gemfile

```
gem "paperclip", git: "git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git"
```

commercial_activities_controller.rb

```
class CommercialActivitiesController < ApplicationController
   ...
  def create
      ...
     @commercial_activity = current_tradesman.commercial_activities.build(commercial_activity_params)
      ...
    respond_to do |format|
      if @commercial_activity.save
        format.html { redirect_to url_for(controller: :tradesmen, action: :index), notice: 'Commercial activity was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @commercial_activity }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to url_for(controller: :tradesmen, action: :index), notice: 'Commercial activity was not created.' }
        format.json { render json: @commercial_activity.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end

  def commercial_activity_params
   params.require(:commercial_activity).permit(:avatar, ...)
  end
end
```

config\environments\production.rb

```
...
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/bin/"
...
```

db\migrate\20160408154436_add_attachment_avatar_to_commercial_activities.rb

```
class AddAttachmentAvatarToCommercialActivities < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_table :commercial_activities do |t|
      t.attachment :avatar
    end
  end

  def self.down
    remove_attachment :commercial_activities, :avatar
  end
end
```

How can I solve the problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to either have a column or virtual attribute for `avatar_file_name` (eg `attr_accessor :avatar_file_name`) in your model. Paperclip will cache the form value in this field before saving it.

Comment: Thanks! Now i have this error: `F, [2016-04-08T15:48:35.041614 #24111] FATAL -- :
Paperclip::Errors::MissingRequiredValidatorError (Paperclip::Errors::MissingRequiredValidatorError):
  app/controllers/commercial_activities_controller.rb:50:in `create' `

Comment: This is the validator that I use: `validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/`

Answer (score 0):

As a follow up to Anthony's answer, and the error reads this way, it looks like it wants an `attr_accessor`. However that seems strange to me because I've never needed one to get my paperclip images working. Have you tried giving the model an `attr_accessible`?

```
class CommercialActivity < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  attr_accessible :avatar
  ...
end
```

Comment: My answer, I guess is more for Rails 3. I see now in your controller that you're on Rails 4, using strong params. Still, I've never needed an `attr_accessor` to make my paperclip images work. :/

Comment: with this the server not load the page

Comment: There's no need to do this, as you are using strong params.

Comment: Did you get past the `Paperclip::Errors::MissingRequiredValidatorError`?

Comment: Yes, now i have another error: `NoMethodError (undefined method 'avatar_content_type' for #<CommercialActivity:0x00000005d26400>):
  app/controllers/commercial_activities_controller.rb:50:in 'create'`

Answer (score 0):

So, are you sure you ran your migrations? When you run the migrations with a paperclip attachment, you should get four things: `<attachment>_file_name`, `<attachment>_file_size`, `<attachment>_content_type`, and `<attachment>_updated_at`. It seems like you're missing all of these...

Here's a link to the docs:
https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#usage